# swapping images using pan gesture

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have multiple `UIImageView` added into the main view, each `UIImageView` is displayed in its own parent `UIView` for cropping purpose, each `UIImageView` is also attached to a `PanGestureRecognizer`.

I am curious on how to implement both pan gesturerecgonizer and also allow image swap by dragging one image (A) to hover over the other image (B) and hold, then the image A and B will be swapped (so A is now displayed in old B's UIView).

This is something like the iPhoto app just implemented.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Implement the pan gesture
- In the method which handles the pan gesture check if the frames of
  two imageview's intersect by using **CGRectIntersectsRect**.

  ```
  if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
  {
  if(CGRectIntersectsRect(frame1,frame2))
         // Swap both the imageview's
  }
  ```